# Boost results in Solr by certain field?

Tags: php, apache, solr

I'm pretty new to Solr but I'm trying to integrate it in to my website. I've been looking in ways to "boost" results in Solr queries, but I'm having a hard time understanding how to achieve what I'm trying to do.

I'm trying to "boost" certain results in Solr searches that have the field "userId" set to 1. For example, if there were two documents in the index that had the exact same text relevance but the first document had the "userId" field set to "1" and the other had it set to "4", then the first document would be positioned higher in the results.

Is there anyway I can do this? Thank you very much!

Comment: Oh and by the way, in the future I'll be trying to run a query where it will check if the "userId" field is equal to several values (a user's friend list on a social networking website) and if the result is, it's boosted higher in the results.

Answer (score 6):

There are several ways you can do this:

- [Boost the documents that have userId=1 at index-time](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#Optional_attributes_on_.22doc.22)
- [Boost the field userId of the documents that have userId=1 at index-time](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#Optional_attributes_for_.22field.22)
- [Use a FunctionQuery at query-time](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#query)

Also take a look at the [Solr relevancy FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_increase_the_score_for_specific_documents) where this kind of questions are answered.

Comment: Soo.. the answer to a very specific question is RTFM? :)

Comment: @Vlad: it's not a very specific question, and pointing to exact locations in the documentation is not nearly the same as saying RTFM, especially when you don't know anything about the domain. Also, it's not just the links, I also described briefly what to do. If you can do better, please post an answer.

Answer (score -3):

use "&sort=score desc,userId asc" as parameter might help

Comment: This is not the desired behavior, only the userId =1 should benefit from query result boosting.